# Ionic 2: Modal doesn't close when clicking on backdrop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to run a simple example app with a modal that covers only the lower part of the screen. I want the modal to close when I click on the backdrop which I think is expected behavior. However, nothing happens when clicking the backdrop.
I know about enableBackdropDismiss which should be true by default.
I'm using Ionic-angular 3.2.1.

Homepage:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Modal } from '../modal/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  openModal(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(Modal);
    modal.present();
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Modal Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
</ion-content>
```

Modal:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
})
export class Modal {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }

  closeModal(): void {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-footer>
    <ion-navbar>
        <h4>Modal</h4>
        <p>I'm a Modal</p>
        <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-footer>
```

This is what it looks like when the modal is shown. The modal only closes when clicking the button, not when clicking the background:

[image]

Comment: You can try by modifying the modal template to be `<ion-content (click)="closeModal()"></ion-content><ion-footer>...</ion-footer>`

Comment: isnt the modal covering the screen? how are you clicking on the backdrop?

Comment: @sebaferreras: That's a good idea but then the content covers the backdrop and I would like to see the backdrop.

Comment: @suraj: The Modal covers only the lower part of the screen as you can see in the picture. I want it to close upon clicking the area above it.

Comment: @LukasStäcker you're right, but you can use css to set the background color of the content to be _transparent_...

Comment: Just figured out the same thing and it works! Thanks @sebaferreras :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) If t's ok for you, I'll add this as an answer so we can close the question

Comment: Sure, go ahead. It seems like a hack to me but it works so I don't care ;)

Comment: I completely agree with you, but AFAIK there isn't any other way to achieve this in the current version of Ionic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like we figured out in the comments, one way to solve this would be to add an empty content to the modal, binding the click event of the content to the `closeModal` method, and then setting the background of the content to be *transparent*

```
<ion-content tappable (click)="closeModal()">
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <ion-navbar>
        <h4>Modal</h4>
        <p>I'm a Modal</p>
        <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-footer>
```

And in the component styles:

```
ion-content div.scroll-content {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Hmm when testing this on my device, the performance is pretty bad. It takes a second or two until listening to the click event and after clicking takes another second to close. Any ideas why or what to improve?

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried by adding the `tappable` attribute to the `ion-content` html element?

Answer (score 3):

If someone is looking for a solution for Ionic 5.
Place this Sample inside your global.scss

```
.my-custom-modal-css .modal-wrapper {
    height: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute; 
 }

.modal-shadow{
    display: none;
}
```

Dont forget to add "my-custom-modal" css class.

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: LocationqrviewPage,
  cssClass: 'my-custom-modal-css',
  backdropDismiss: true
});
return await modal.present();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only css problem.

please add to the app.scss

```
@media not all and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  ion-modal ion-backdrop {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

this snippet will display your backdrop (it's hidden for small screens)

and

```
.modal-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

to set your modals not full-width and height sized (by default)
and it should be absolutely positioned for avoiding problems on iOS devices, which will render backdrop front of modal.

BTW you shouldn't now place your content inside the  - it's not really good practice. But in this case you can set modal position as you wish and use all needed elements and rules without header or footer restrictions.

Comment: In my case I was using the modal in the center of the screen and adding  visibility: visible; works for me. Thanks